# PHP script saves empty image files when run as cron job

Tags: php, cron, cpanel

I have a script that downloads images from the external server and saves them in a folder at the root of the website. The script file is also in the root of the website.

folder for images: /public_html/images/

script: /public_html/script.php

When i run file manually (example.com/script.php) all downloaded image files are saved in the folder correctly. But when the file is executed by the cron job all the images are saved with sizes of 0 bytes.

I've tried to empty the folder before the cron job run. I've changed the permissions to 777. Log file when the script runs manually and as cron looks the same.

The cron job is set up in the cpanel crontab.

Please help me figure out what is going on.

```
$dir = "/home/example/public_html/images/";

foreach (scandir($dir) as $item) {
    if ($item == '.' || $item == '..') continue; 
    unlink($dir.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$item);
}
$ftp_server = 'www2.housescape.org.uk';
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$ftp_user = 'user';
$ftp_pass = 'password';
ftp_set_option($ftp_conn, FTP_TIMEOUT_SEC, 3600);
if(ftp_login($ftp_conn, $ftp_user, $ftp_pass)){
            ftp_pasv($ftp_conn, true);

            $images = ftp_nlist($ftp_conn, '/images/'); 
            $c = 0;
            foreach($images as $image){
                $c = $c + 1;

                echo "ftp://user:password@www2.housescape.org.uk:21".$image." / ";  
                $urltoget="ftp://user:password@www2.housescape.org.uk:21".$image;
                echo $thefile=basename($image);
                echo "<br>"; 

                $content = file_get_contents("ftp://user:password@www2.housescape.org.uk:21".$image);
                file_put_contents("/home/example/public_html/images/".$thefile, $content);

            }
            if ($count1>0) { echo "No File Change"; }
            ftp_close($ftp_conn);
}
else{
    echo 'Failed Login!';
}
```

Comment: Please post the contents of script.php

Comment: You should check whether `file_get_contents()` is successful before writing to the file.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar `file_get_contents()` is returning successfully when running manually but false when from the cron job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is only a suggestion to help track down the error, not an answer:*

Did you check whether the CRON PHP environment has [allow_url_fopen](http://php.net/manual/de/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) enabled?

```
<?php

if (!ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
  die("'allow_url_fopen' is not enabled in the php.ini");
}
```

Comment: This  is technically a comment .. Not an answer, as it's a question and a suggestion on how to check for something.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot comment on questions/answers except for my own below 50 reputation. Sorry, if this was misleading to you.

Comment: Thanks, @Sven, 'allow_url_fopen' was disabled. I've enabled it in php.ini and user.ini with `allow_url_fopen = On` but the error log is still showing `ftp:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0 `. Any ideas what may be the reason?

Comment: If PHP is running via FPM, you have to restart the FPM service after making changes to the php.ini

Comment: @SvenMich Looks like you got enough rep yesterday that you can now comment.

Comment: Turning off FPM seems to do the trick. The cron job is working now. Thank you kindly @Sven